# Adding product description , product image etc in custom Transactional Email for New order

Tags: magento

I have created a new custom template using the New order default template in my Magento admin panel.
There are some default variables available to be inserted into the email. But I want to add some other variables like product description into the email template.

In my email after order creation , I want to send description and other details of all products that are present in my cart.

What I have in template is :

```
    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">

        <tr>
            <td valign="top">

            <img src="xyz.jpg"/>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>

          <?php 
         $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId("{{var order.increment_id}}");
         $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
         foreach($items as $i):
          echo $i->getProductId();
          echo $i->getDescription();
          echo $i->getDescription();
         endforeach;
         ?>
           </td>
        </tr>
```

I want to achieve something like this. Is it possible adding PHP code into the email template and get the variables working. Or I have to define this php code somewhere else? If yes, can you please specify where to make these changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I dont think u need to load product object in email template it is already loaded if not u can do that but sure u dont need sales order object that sure.

app\design\frontend\default\imsov2\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
```

and so on...